# SetCueBanner not working on multi-line edit control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cedit

I have created an edit control with multi-line style. I used SetCueBanner for displaying some text as tip. It displays the text only when I remove the ES_MULTILINE style, but with this style the text is not displayed.
Why is this happening and how to display the Cue Banner text with multi-line style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "standard" way to show a cue banner for ES_MULTILINE.

The docs clearly state that this isn't possible for multiline or RTF controls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want to do such a thing, you need to subclass the control and do your own painting if the Control contains no text and has the focus.